# EnumServicesStatus and Windows 7

Tags: winapi

All these years i have been successfully using EnumServicesStatus in combination with OpenScManager (with SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE) to get a list of the services installed on a computer. This has been working well since NT 4 and up to Vista.

Now, for some reason, in Windows 7 I'm not getting the whole list of the installed services, but only a few of them. No errors, just a very incomplete list of services

Has anything changed in Windows 7? Do I need administrative powers now to enumerate services (I hope that's not the case)? Using Delphi 2010 but the same code was working file in D2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything has changed here. It would cause huge incompatibilities with old software. But D2007 used the ansi version ENUM_SERVICE_STATUSA and I think D2010 calls the unicode version ENUM_SERVICE_STATUSW. Maybe you are doing some manipulation in the results that assume that the result is ANSI when you are getting Unicode? Just guessing.

Comment: Will check this out, but you may be into something here.